# Apriori Algorithm: What am i doing wrong with transactions

Tags: r, transactions, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I'm trying to run an Apriori algorithm on a dataset that I have

Here is the code that I'm running

```
data <- opp %>%
 left_join(products, by = "product_id") %>%
 left_join(aisles, by ="aisle_id") %>%
 group_by(order_id) %>%
 summarise(basket = as.vector(list(aisle)))

 transaction_prior<-as(data,"transactions")
 aisle_basket_rules <- apriori(transaction_prior, parameter = list(support=0.1, confidence = 0.6, minlen=3,maxlen=10,target = "rules"))
 aisle_basket_rules
```

When I try to create a `transaction` object variable name: `transaction_prior` 
I get an following error:

```
  Error in asMethod(object) : 
   column(s) 1, 2 not logical or a factor. Discretize the columns first.
```

I tried `discretize` method as well instead of using `summarise` method from dplyr, but my apriori wouldn't give any results, either it would take to long or return 0 rules.

Can anyone explain to me where am I going wrong?

Here is the data present in `data` variable:

> kable(head(data,25))

```
   order_id basket
   2    c(42, 54, 123, 90, 7, 54, 40, 125, 99)
   3    c(134, 120, 99, 99, 120, 54, 105, 12)
   4    c(13, 30, 43, 14, 14, 14, 14, 26, 129, 33, 111, 44, 44)
   5    c(51, 113, 107, 99, 84, 100, 132, 78, 96, 94, 75, 97, 32, 19, 54,125, 100, 32, 11, 94, 100, 51, 41, 51, 51, 33)
   6    c(111, 80, 1)
   7    c(111, 63)
   8    17
   9    c(54, 99, 99, 134, 32, 20, 54, 90, 132, 12, 12, 76, 120, 94, 67)
   10   c(51, 54, 52, 51, 54, 52, 51, 5, 5, 22, 54, 34, 83, 54, 54)
   11   c(60, 50, 22, 26, 90)
   12   c(34, 84, 54, 34, 76, 76, 76, 76, 119, 61, 129, 129, 129, 55, 39)
   13   c(10, 108, 124, 118, 108, 44, 44, 111, 132, 118, 93, 93, 26)
   14   c(29, 84, 57, 55, 94, 25, 134, 56, 2, 63, 51)
   15   c(132, 90, 22, 117, 117)
   16   c(104, 132, 26)
   18   c(100, 54, 15, 99, 84, 132, 51, 99, 5, 51, 54, 18, 2, 63, 22, 5, 5,31, 125, 31, 89, 54, 125, 54, 71, 54, 51, 106)
   19   c(99, 120, 54)
   20   c(32, 57, 54, 134, 44, 51, 51, 26)
   21   c(127, 127, 51, 94, 29)
   22   c(84, 12, 51, 54, 99, 42, 94, 54, 105, 81, 13, 93, 54, 49)
   23   c(99, 54, 54, 54, 51, 41, 64, 127, 51, 54, 93, 113, 19, 91)
   24   c(72, 72, 72)
   25   c(104, 104, 63, 57, 94, 94, 42, 71, 55, 39, 62, 60, 94, 99)
   26   c(120, 51, 51, 96, 42, 99, 63, 51)
   27   c(51, 134, 50, 50, 19, 119, 51, 54, 93, 54, 21, 22, 127, 54, 101, 54, 54, 94, 41, 99, 63, 63, 127, 54, 7, 7, 49)
```

Here is the `dput` dump of the `data` variable:

> dput(head(data, 5))
>
> structure(list(order_id = 2:6, basket = list(structure(c(42L, 
>   54L, 123L, 90L, 7L, 54L, 40L, 125L, 99L), .Label = c("air fresheners candles", 
>   "asian foods", "baby accessories", "baby bath body care", "baby food formula", 
>   "bakery desserts", "baking ingredients", "baking supplies decor", 
>   "beauty", "beers coolers", "body lotions soap", "bread", "breakfast bakery", 
>   "breakfast bars pastries", "bulk dried fruits vegetables", "bulk grains rice dried goods", 
>   "buns rolls", "butter", "candy chocolate", "canned fruit applesauce", 
>   "canned jarred vegetables", "canned meals beans", "canned meat seafood", 
>   "cat food care", "cereal", "chips pretzels", "cleaning products", 
>   "cocoa drink mixes", "coffee", "cold flu allergy", "condiments", 
>   "cookies cakes", "crackers", "cream", "deodorants", "diapers wipes", 
>   "digestion", "dish detergents", "dog food care", "doughs gelatins bake mixes", 
>   "dry pasta", "eggs", "energy granola bars", "energy sports drinks", 
>   "eye ear care", "facial care", "feminine care", "first aid", 
>   "food storage", "fresh dips tapenades", "fresh fruits", "fresh herbs", 
>   "fresh pasta", "fresh vegetables", "frozen appetizers sides", 
>   "frozen breads doughs", "frozen breakfast", "frozen dessert", 
>   "frozen juice", "frozen meals", "frozen meat seafood", "frozen pizza", 
>   "frozen produce", "frozen vegan vegetarian", "fruit vegetable snacks", 
>   "grains rice dried goods", "granola", "hair care", "honeys syrups nectars", 
>   "hot cereal pancake mixes", "hot dogs bacon sausage", "ice cream ice", 
>   "ice cream toppings", "indian foods", "instant foods", "juice nectars", 
>   "kitchen supplies", "kosher foods", "latino foods", "laundry", 
>   "lunch meat", "marinades meat preparation", "meat counter", "milk", 
>   "mint gum", "missing", "more household", "muscles joints pain relief", 
>   "nuts seeds dried fruit", "oils vinegars", "oral hygiene", "other", 
>   "other creams cheeses", "packaged cheese", "packaged meat", "packaged poultry", 
>   "packaged produce", "packaged seafood", "packaged vegetables fruits", 
>   "paper goods", "pasta sauce", "pickled goods olives", "plates bowls cups flatware", 
>   "popcorn jerky", "poultry counter", "prepared meals", "prepared soups salads", 
>   "preserved dips spreads", "protein meal replacements", "red wines", 
>   "refrigerated", "refrigerated pudding desserts", "salad dressing toppings", 
>   "seafood counter", "shave needs", "skin care", "soap", "soft drinks", 
>   "soup broth bouillon", "soy lactosefree", "specialty cheeses", 
>   "specialty wines champagnes", "spices seasonings", "spirits", 
>   "spreads", "tea", "tofu meat alternatives", "tortillas flat bread", 
>   "trail mix snack mix", "trash bags liners", "vitamins supplements", 
>   "water seltzer sparkling water", "white wines", "yogurt"), class = "factor"), 
>       structure(c(134L, 120L, 99L, 99L, 120L, 54L, 105L, 12L), .Label = c("air fresheners candles", 
>       "asian foods", "baby accessories", "baby bath body care", 
>       "baby food formula", "bakery desserts", "baking ingredients", 
>       "baking supplies decor", "beauty", "beers coolers", "body lotions soap", 
>       "bread", "breakfast bakery", "breakfast bars pastries", "bulk dried fruits vegetables", 
>       "bulk grains rice dried goods", "buns rolls", "butter", "candy chocolate", 
>       "canned fruit applesauce", "canned jarred vegetables", "canned meals beans", 
>       "canned meat seafood", "cat food care", "cereal", "chips pretzels", 
>       "cleaning products", "cocoa drink mixes", "coffee", "cold flu allergy", 
>       "condiments", "cookies cakes", "crackers", "cream", "deodorants", 
>       "diapers wipes", "digestion", "dish detergents", "dog food care", 
>       "doughs gelatins bake mixes", "dry pasta", "eggs", "energy granola bars", 
>       "energy sports drinks", "eye ear care", "facial care", "feminine care", 
>       "first aid", "food storage", "fresh dips tapenades", "fresh fruits", 
>       "fresh herbs", "fresh pasta", "fresh vegetables", "frozen appetizers sides", 
>       "frozen breads doughs", "frozen breakfast", "frozen dessert", 
>       "frozen juice", "frozen meals", "frozen meat seafood", "frozen pizza", 
>       "frozen produce", "frozen vegan vegetarian", "fruit vegetable snacks", 
>       "grains rice dried goods", "granola", "hair care", "honeys syrups nectars", 
>       "hot cereal pancake mixes", "hot dogs bacon sausage", "ice cream ice", 
>       "ice cream toppings", "indian foods", "instant foods", "juice nectars", 
>       "kitchen supplies", "kosher foods", "latino foods", "laundry", 
>       "lunch meat", "marinades meat preparation", "meat counter", 
>       "milk", "mint gum", "missing", "more household", "muscles joints pain relief", 
>       "nuts seeds dried fruit", "oils vinegars", "oral hygiene", 
>       "other", "other creams cheeses", "packaged cheese", "packaged meat", 
>       "packaged poultry", "packaged produce", "packaged seafood", 
>       "packaged vegetables fruits", "paper goods", "pasta sauce", 
>       "pickled goods olives", "plates bowls cups flatware", "popcorn jerky", 
>       "poultry counter", "prepared meals", "prepared soups salads", 
>       "preserved dips spreads", "protein meal replacements", "red wines", 
>       "refrigerated", "refrigerated pudding desserts", "salad dressing toppings", 
>       "seafood counter", "shave needs", "skin care", "soap", "soft drinks", 
>       "soup broth bouillon", "soy lactosefree", "specialty cheeses", 
>       "specialty wines champagnes", "spices seasonings", "spirits", 
>       "spreads", "tea", "tofu meat alternatives", "tortillas flat bread", 
>       "trail mix snack mix", "trash bags liners", "vitamins supplements", 
>       "water seltzer sparkling water", "white wines", "yogurt"), class = "factor"), 
>       structure(c(13L, 30L, 43L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 26L, 129L, 
>       33L, 111L, 44L, 44L), .Label = c("air fresheners candles", 
>       "asian foods", "baby accessories", "baby bath body care", 
>       "baby food formula", "bakery desserts", "baking ingredients", 
>       "baking supplies decor", "beauty", "beers coolers", "body lotions soap", 
>       "bread", "breakfast bakery", "breakfast bars pastries", "bulk dried fruits vegetables", 
>       "bulk grains rice dried goods", "buns rolls", "butter", "candy chocolate", 
>       "canned fruit applesauce", "canned jarred vegetables", "canned meals beans", 
>       "canned meat seafood", "cat food care", "cereal", "chips pretzels", 
>       "cleaning products", "cocoa drink mixes", "coffee", "cold flu allergy", 
>       "condiments", "cookies cakes", "crackers", "cream", "deodorants", 
>       "diapers wipes", "digestion", "dish detergents", "dog food care", 
>       "doughs gelatins bake mixes", "dry pasta", "eggs", "energy granola bars", 
>       "energy sports drinks", "eye ear care", "facial care", "feminine care", 
>       "first aid", "food storage", "fresh dips tapenades", "fresh fruits", 
>       "fresh herbs", "fresh pasta", "fresh vegetables", "frozen appetizers sides", 
>       "frozen breads doughs", "frozen breakfast", "frozen dessert", 
>       "frozen juice", "frozen meals", "frozen meat seafood", "frozen pizza", 
>       "frozen produce", "frozen vegan vegetarian", "fruit vegetable snacks", 
>       "grains rice dried goods", "granola", "hair care", "honeys syrups nectars", 
>       "hot cereal pancake mixes", "hot dogs bacon sausage", "ice cream ice", 
>       "ice cream toppings", "indian foods", "instant foods", "juice nectars", 
>       "kitchen supplies", "kosher foods", "latino foods", "laundry", 
>       "lunch meat", "marinades meat preparation", "meat counter", 
>       "milk", "mint gum", "missing", "more household", "muscles joints pain relief", 
>       "nuts seeds dried fruit", "oils vinegars", "oral hygiene", 
>       "other", "other creams cheeses", "packaged cheese", "packaged meat", 
>       "packaged poultry", "packaged produce", "packaged seafood", 
>       "packaged vegetables fruits", "paper goods", "pasta sauce", 
>       "pickled goods olives", "plates bowls cups flatware", "popcorn jerky", 
>       "poultry counter", "prepared meals", "prepared soups salads", 
>       "preserved dips spreads", "protein meal replacements", "red wines", 
>       "refrigerated", "refrigerated pudding desserts", "salad dressing toppings", 
>       "seafood counter", "shave needs", "skin care", "soap", "soft drinks", 
>       "soup broth bouillon", "soy lactosefree", "specialty cheeses", 
>       "specialty wines champagnes", "spices seasonings", "spirits", 
>       "spreads", "tea", "tofu meat alternatives", "tortillas flat bread", 
>       "trail mix snack mix", "trash bags liners", "vitamins supplements", 
>       "water seltzer sparkling water", "white wines", "yogurt"), class = "factor"), 
>       structure(c(51L, 113L, 107L, 99L, 84L, 100L, 132L, 78L, 96L, 
>       94L, 75L, 97L, 32L, 19L, 54L, 125L, 100L, 32L, 11L, 94L, 
>       100L, 51L, 41L, 51L, 51L, 33L), .Label = c("air fresheners candles", 
>       "asian foods", "baby accessories", "baby bath body care", 
>       "baby food formula", "bakery desserts", "baking ingredients", 
>       "baking supplies decor", "beauty", "beers coolers", "body lotions soap", 
>       "bread", "breakfast bakery", "breakfast bars pastries", "bulk dried fruits vegetables", 
>       "bulk grains rice dried goods", "buns rolls", "butter", "candy chocolate", 
>       "canned fruit applesauce", "canned jarred vegetables", "canned meals beans", 
>       "canned meat seafood", "cat food care", "cereal", "chips pretzels", 
>       "cleaning products", "cocoa drink mixes", "coffee", "cold flu allergy", 
>       "condiments", "cookies cakes", "crackers", "cream", "deodorants", 
>       "diapers wipes", "digestion", "dish detergents", "dog food care", 
>       "doughs gelatins bake mixes", "dry pasta", "eggs", "energy granola bars", 
>       "energy sports drinks", "eye ear care", "facial care", "feminine care", 
>       "first aid", "food storage", "fresh dips tapenades", "fresh fruits", 
>       "fresh herbs", "fresh pasta", "fresh vegetables", "frozen appetizers sides", 
>       "frozen breads doughs", "frozen breakfast", "frozen dessert", 
>       "frozen juice", "frozen meals", "frozen meat seafood", "frozen pizza", 
>       "frozen produce", "frozen vegan vegetarian", "fruit vegetable snacks", 
>       "grains rice dried goods", "granola", "hair care", "honeys syrups nectars", 
>       "hot cereal pancake mixes", "hot dogs bacon sausage", "ice cream ice", 
>       "ice cream toppings", "indian foods", "instant foods", "juice nectars", 
>       "kitchen supplies", "kosher foods", "latino foods", "laundry", 
>       "lunch meat", "marinades meat preparation", "meat counter", 
>       "milk", "mint gum", "missing", "more household", "muscles joints pain relief", 
>       "nuts seeds dried fruit", "oils vinegars", "oral hygiene", 
>       "other", "other creams cheeses", "packaged cheese", "packaged meat", 
>       "packaged poultry", "packaged produce", "packaged seafood", 
>       "packaged vegetables fruits", "paper goods", "pasta sauce", 
>       "pickled goods olives", "plates bowls cups flatware", "popcorn jerky", 
>       "poultry counter", "prepared meals", "prepared soups salads", 
>       "preserved dips spreads", "protein meal replacements", "red wines", 
>       "refrigerated", "refrigerated pudding desserts", "salad dressing toppings", 
>       "seafood counter", "shave needs", "skin care", "soap", "soft drinks", 
>       "soup broth bouillon", "soy lactosefree", "specialty cheeses", 
>       "specialty wines champagnes", "spices seasonings", "spirits", 
>       "spreads", "tea", "tofu meat alternatives", "tortillas flat bread", 
>       "trail mix snack mix", "trash bags liners", "vitamins supplements", 
>       "water seltzer sparkling water", "white wines", "yogurt"), class = "factor"), 
>       structure(c(111L, 80L, 1L), .Label = c("air fresheners candles", 
>       "asian foods", "baby accessories", "baby bath body care", 
>       "baby food formula", "bakery desserts", "baking ingredients", 
>       "baking supplies decor", "beauty", "beers coolers", "body lotions soap", 
>       "bread", "breakfast bakery", "breakfast bars pastries", "bulk dried fruits vegetables", 
>       "bulk grains rice dried goods", "buns rolls", "butter", "candy chocolate", 
>       "canned fruit applesauce", "canned jarred vegetables", "canned meals beans", 
>       "canned meat seafood", "cat food care", "cereal", "chips pretzels", 
>       "cleaning products", "cocoa drink mixes", "coffee", "cold flu allergy", 
>       "condiments", "cookies cakes", "crackers", "cream", "deodorants", 
>       "diapers wipes", "digestion", "dish detergents", "dog food care", 
>       "doughs gelatins bake mixes", "dry pasta", "eggs", "energy granola bars", 
>       "energy sports drinks", "eye ear care", "facial care", "feminine care", 
>       "first aid", "food storage", "fresh dips tapenades", "fresh fruits", 
>       "fresh herbs", "fresh pasta", "fresh vegetables", "frozen appetizers sides", 
>       "frozen breads doughs", "frozen breakfast", "frozen dessert", 
>       "frozen juice", "frozen meals", "frozen meat seafood", "frozen pizza", 
>       "frozen produce", "frozen vegan vegetarian", "fruit vegetable snacks", 
>       "grains rice dried goods", "granola", "hair care", "honeys syrups nectars", 
>       "hot cereal pancake mixes", "hot dogs bacon sausage", "ice cream ice", 
>       "ice cream toppings", "indian foods", "instant foods", "juice nectars", 
>       "kitchen supplies", "kosher foods", "latino foods", "laundry", 
>       "lunch meat", "marinades meat preparation", "meat counter", 
>       "milk", "mint gum", "missing", "more household", "muscles joints pain relief", 
>       "nuts seeds dried fruit", "oils vinegars", "oral hygiene", 
>       "other", "other creams cheeses", "packaged cheese", "packaged meat", 
>       "packaged poultry", "packaged produce", "packaged seafood", 
>       "packaged vegetables fruits", "paper goods", "pasta sauce", 
>       "pickled goods olives", "plates bowls cups flatware", "popcorn jerky", 
>       "poultry counter", "prepared meals", "prepared soups salads", 
>       "preserved dips spreads", "protein meal replacements", "red wines", 
>       "refrigerated", "refrigerated pudding desserts", "salad dressing toppings", 
>       "seafood counter", "shave needs", "skin care", "soap", "soft drinks", 
>       "soup broth bouillon", "soy lactosefree", "specialty cheeses", 
>       "specialty wines champagnes", "spices seasonings", "spirits", 
>       "spreads", "tea", "tofu meat alternatives", "tortillas flat bread", 
>       "trail mix snack mix", "trash bags liners", "vitamins supplements", 
>       "water seltzer sparkling water", "white wines", "yogurt"), class = "factor"))), .Names = c("order_id", 
>   "basket"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
>   "data.frame"))

Comment: I think you could reduce your input/output so it would look more a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, let me try, i cant fig out how to reduce the dput dump